# How can i use [Authorize] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] in API Post request?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, antiforgerytoken

I have created an webapi and MVC project with Angular 1. Also created some apis. I have also used oauth in my project. I have set [Autorize] in my api controller. I have also added RequestVerificationToken in my view file. Now i am calling api on submit button. I need to pass both [Authorize] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] on post api. I am getting two issues

1. A claim of type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' or 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider' was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity. To enable anti-forgery token support with claims-based authentication, please verify that the configured claims provider is providing both of these claims on the ClaimsIdentity instances it generates. If the configured claims provider instead uses a different claim type as a unique identifier, it can be configured by setting the static property AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier.'

This issue i have fixed after adding below line in global.aspx.cs file.
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Email;

2. Now i am facing second issue. The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.

i am not clear with this issue.

can i use both attributes on my post hit simultaneously?